# Can't mark emails as Not Junk in Outlook 2013

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, gmail

When I try to mark an email as Not Junk in Outlook 2013, I typically get a dialog that says `The operation cannot be performed because the message has been changed.` This happens about 90% of the time. The account in question is a Gmail account linked via IMAP. I can (obviously) mark the email as not spam successfully using Gmail's web interface. How can I fix this problem so I can mark items as Not Junk from Outlook itself?